# How do I remove the extra comma in this CSV generator for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, csv, iteration

I have a group of objects nested inside of an array.

I understand why the for loop is adding a comma at the end of the rows, but I'm having trouble finding out a better way to write this (brand-new to programming) which would not have the comma inside of the loop.

Is there a better way to write this?

```
function createCSV() {
    
    // CREATE THE CSV VARIABLE
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
    let headers = "date,account,vendor,amount,recurring,description,notes"
    csvContent += headers + "\r\n"
    
    // ITERATE THE ARRAY INTO THE CSV SEPARATED BY COMMAS
    adjustments.forEach(element => {

        // EACH ARRAY ITEM
        let row
        
        //EACH OBJECT PROPERTY
        for (const property in element) {
            row += element[property]
            row += ','
          }

        csvContent += row + "\r\n";
    });

    // DOWNLOAD THE CSV
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "empower_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
    link.click();
    console.log('CSV DOWNLOADED')
}
```

Comment: Just `let row = element.join(',') + '\r\n';`

Comment: or even  `csvContent += element.join(',;)+ "\r\n";`

Comment: @AdityaParab - you assume element is an array - adjustments is an array ... but who knows what each element is

Comment: @JaromandaX Yep, since the CSV is being generated, I'd assume it to be an array of strings.

Comment: each element could be an array of strings ... or an object (why else would the code use for ... in, since OP knows how to iterate an array)

Comment: I guess the question needs to be asked ... what is `adjustments` an array of? objects? arrays of strings?

Comment: Adjustments is an array of Objects | Each array entry is an adjustment object

Comment: word of warning ... property order isn't guaranteed in objects ... so, depending on how the objects (`element`) are created, they could end up in the wrong order (with respect to the csv header) - just something to keep in mind

Comment: @JaromandaX that's a good call out, I didn't know that.
Should I use an Array instead, to add each property in the same order?

It's simple transaction data. Types listed in the headers variable in my code. (price, date, etc)

Comment: depends on how you get the data and if you do anything with it before this code ... you could have an array of strings, being the properties in the object, then iterate through that - in my third code in my answer, that would be `csvContent += adjustments.map(element => properties.map(prop => element[prop]).join(',')).join('\r\n');` ... if `properties` was an array of strings like `const properties = ['date','account','vendor','amount','recurring','description','notes']` (I'm assuming property names = your column names, they don't have to)

Comment: @itsmitchellcollins - I've added to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use array and array join

```
function createCSV() {
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    let headers = "date,account,vendor,amount,recurring,description,notes";
    csvContent += headers + "\r\n";

    adjustments.forEach(element => {
        // begin changes
        let row = [];
        for (const property in element) {
            row.push(element[property]);
        }
        csvContent += row.join(',') + "\r\n";
        // end changes
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "empower_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    console.log('CSV DOWNLOADED');
}
```

better yet - replace all that with

```
function createCSV() {
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    let headers = "date,account,vendor,amount,recurring,description,notes";
    csvContent += headers + "\r\n";

    adjustments.forEach(element => {
        // begin changes
        csvContent += Object.values(element).join(',') + "\r\n";
        // end changes
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "empower_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    console.log('CSV DOWNLOADED');
}
```

or for really neat code

```
function createCSV() {
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    let headers = "date,account,vendor,amount,recurring,description,notes";

    csvContent += headers + "\r\n";
    // begin changes
    csvContent += adjustments.map(
        element => Object.values(element).join(',')
    ).join('\r\n');
    // end changes
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "empower_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    console.log('CSV DOWNLOADED');
}
```

As a final note: since object properties don't have a defined "order" - you may want to do something like this

```
function createCSV() {
    const properties = ['date','account','vendor','amount','recurring','description','notes'];
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    let headers = "date,account,vendor,amount,recurring,description,notes";

    csvContent += headers + "\r\n";
    // begin changes
    csvContent += adjustments.map(element => properties.map(prop => element[prop]).join(',')).join('\r\n');
    // end changes
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "empower_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    console.log('CSV DOWNLOADED');
}
```

In the above, I assume the property names in the object are the same as the CSV column headers, but, of course, that's not necessarily the case (I simply don't know)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because if (a) your helpful quotes to show me exactly where you changed code (b) thank you for showing me how to simplify this. I actually understand exactly what you did, and why. It took me a few minutes of reviewing, but I understand it completely. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for that is to use array instead of string concatenation and finish this with `array.join()` :

```js
function createCSV() {
    
    // CREATE THE CSV VARIABLE
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
    let headers = "date,account,vendor,amount,recurring,description,notes"
    csvContent += headers + "\r\n"
    
    // ITERATE THE ARRAY INTO THE CSV SEPARATED BY COMMAS
    adjustments.forEach(element => {

        // EACH ARRAY ITEM
        const row = [];
        
        //EACH OBJECT PROPERTY
        for (const property in element) {
            row.push(element[property]);
        }

        csvContent += row.join(',') + "\r\n";
    });

    // DOWNLOAD THE CSV
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "empower_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
    link.click();
    console.log('CSV DOWNLOADED')
}
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. This helped me because I didn't know about .join. I will use this in the future!